# Reloading page when the user clicks on the back button in browser

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, back-button

I have developed a small application using Classic ASP and VBScript. It's currently running in my company. When a user clicks on log out, the session expires. I have put further controls in the database. When Log out is clicked, the user status changes to Signed Out in database. This prevents a user to click on any link even if he goes to the previous page by clicking the back button after logging out.

However, what I want is that after logging out, if the user clicks on Back button in browser, the previous page should not show up at all. Rather a default error message which I decide should show up. Is there any way in Classic ASP to accomplish this?

Comment: Set the [no-cache pragma](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html#pragma) to instruct the client to not cache the page (i.e. request it from the server every time).

Answer (score 2):

What I have been using for years to prevent caching is the following (place it in a separate file and include on each front-end asp page)

```
<%
Response.Expires = 60
Response.Expiresabsolute = Now() - 1
Response.AddHeader "pragma","no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "cache-control","private"
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
%>
```

Other than that I that you should use session.abandon on your log off page and
then you can use Session_OnStart with a redirect to your default launch page.
Or if you really want that error page, a Session.clear and function to redirect to that error page if the session has been cleared.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try this now and get back to you.